# async_stream Stream Types

Tags: rust, stream

Consider the following minimal stream example:

```rust
use futures::StreamExt;
use async_stream::stream;

#[tokio::main]
async fn main() {
    let ticks = stream! {
        yield Ok(0);
        yield Err("");
    };
    futures::pin_mut!(ticks);
    while let Some(x) = ticks.next().await {
        println!("{:?}", x);
    }
}
```

What is the proper type of `ticks`?

This surprisingly simple problem has stopped me from creating a function. The correct type should work with a function signature.

```rust
use futures::StreamExt;
use async_stream::stream;

fn query() -> ???? {
    return stream! {
        yield Ok(0);
        yield Err("");
    };
}

#[tokio::main]
async fn main() {
    let ticks = query();
    futures::pin_mut!(ticks);
    while let Some(x) = ticks.next().await {
        println!("{:?}", x);
    }
}
```

How do you find out types?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The actual type is [`async_stream::AsyncStream<Result<i32, &'static str>, [some_compiler_generated_future_type]>`](https://docs.rs/async-stream/0.3.3/src/async_stream/async_stream.rs.html#8-14), but you should not specify it, for two reasons:

1. You *cannot* specify it, because you cannot name `[some_compiler_generated_future_type]`.
2. Even if you sidestep this problem (for example by using `impl Trait`), `AsyncStream` is mentioned nowhere in `async_stream`'s documentation, because it is marked `#[doc(hidden)]` - and this is a strong signal the authors of the library consider it an implementation detail that may change, and expect you to not rely on it.

The library docs do no mention how to do that, which is quite unfortunate, but given that we want to return "some stream", we can express it using `impl Stream<Item = YieldType>`. You cannot do that in local variable declarations ([yet](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/63065)), but you can at function return type position:

```rust
fn query() -> impl futures::Stream<Item = Result<i32, &'static str>>
```

Comment: Are you saying that it's impossible to complete the statement `let x : (???) = query()`? That's very confusing.

Comment: @Test Practically yes. If you need that, you can use trait objects.

Comment: Do you mind adding how you figured out that the function needed not to be `async`? It's ok if not. It may help other readers.